# Javascript library memory caching

Tags: javascript, web, browser, shared-libraries

does browsers cache interpreted javascript bytecode?

Comment: Ever heard of "Cache"?

Comment: i'm not a web developer so forgive me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the [Expires header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Expires) (date/time after which the response is considered stale).
Basically, the first time your browser reaches to a server to get the file, the server responds with something like "here's the file, store it for as long as you can".

Then the browser uses its cache to store it there. The cache size is usually configurable so you can't know how much it is.

After a resource expires, the browser would then request and store it again.

Most CDNs would attempt to store their static resources for a year in your browser's cache. If they change something, they normally change the resource's name by appending a parameter (e.g. `http://example.com/js/jquery.js?v=1`) and your browser would recognize it as a new file.

All of the above is somewhat simplified but should work as a general description.